# How to detect two-fingers double tap in QML?

Tags: qml

How to detect two-fingers double tap in QML? Does it reachable somehow with QML classes out-of-the-box? Or, do I need to play with timer and MultiPointHandler QML Type?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not out-of-the-box solution. you should implement it yourself using the tools you mentioned

Comment: Thx, I will, it looks trivial. Just don't want reinvent the wheel.